# Load single cell in query in excel

Tags: excel, database

I have n excel files with the same layout, and i want to create a recap file where some info is reported for each file. The info is located in the same specific cells, for example d2 and e2 in every file.

What is the best way to do it? The file names vary without logic and that people that access that file have no skills in coding and macro, so i try to develop something very simple.

I also have no skill in database, but i have managed to create a query with every file in the folder, i have then created a column with the data but i am not able to say that i only want a specific cell, is there a way to do it?

here is a picture of the situation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A formula using `INDIRECT` can be used, but it will generate a **#REF** error when the workbook is closed. you could use your macro to open the relevant workbook, and then close it after saving the values

the indirect formula would look something like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'[Test File.xlxs]Test Data'!$A$7")
```

or, as a formula using your data:

```
=INDIRECT("[" & B1 & "]YourSheet!$E$2")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already know the funciton INDIRECT, I was searching for something more "clean". I built a database from folder that is updated when loading the query, i was trying to add a custom column with the data i need for every file, but honestly, i really don't know if it is possible.